# Indeterminate forms by limits

Tags: calculus

Suppose we were told to find the limit of $\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2 \sin x}$ as $x$ approches $0$. This is fairly simple using L'hopitals rule. Now the function can be written as $\frac{\cos x}{x \sin x}-\frac{1}{x^2}$.By applying the properties of limits we see that the desired limit is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x}{x \sin x}-\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}$. Both of these give limits infinity,so shouldn't the resulting limit be indeterminate? Though L'hopitals rule gives a numeric answer of $\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known and major misconception in limits.  Note:-
$\lim (f(x)+g(x))=\lim f(x) +\lim g(x)$ if both $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exists separately.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you want a counter example then the one you have in your question is more than sufficient. Otherwise you can consider an example from sequences. Take $\{x_{n}\}=(-1)^{n}$ and $\{y_{n}\}=(-1)^{n-1}$. Then the limit of $x_{n}+y_{n}$ is $0$ as each term is zero. But neither xn nor yn have a limit. Both are divergent oscillatory sequences.